# Divide load in different requests in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have to perform a load test in which I've to divide my load in different requests.
For example, there are 100 users
30 in Registration
30 in Home page
30 in Dashboard
10 in Search products
I'm not sure which approach should be followed.
Suggestions are appreciated.
Thanks in Advance:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put each request under [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller) and define relevant total executions

> For example, if using total execution mode, and uncheck "per user", then the number given for throughput will be the total number of executions made

Answer (score 0):

Normally you should be using different [Thread Groups](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) to represent different groups of business users so I think you should create 4 different Thread Groups and divide your 100 users according to your scenario

If you want/need to keep them in a single Thread Group (i.e. they all need to be logged in prior to doing other stuff) you can use one of the following logic controllers:

- [Throughput Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Throughput_Controller)
- [Switch Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Switch_Controller)
- [Weighted Switch Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/wsc/WeightedSwitchController.md)

More information: [Running JMeter Samplers with Defined Percentage Probability](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-jmeter-samplers-defined-percentage-probability)

Answer (score 0):

It's common a **misconception** when trying to achieve a targeted percentage of requests to instantiate Vusers in the same proportion. This **only** works if the Avg Response Time (ART) of each type of request is the same. It's very unlikely that, for example, the *search* ART will the same RT as the *registration* request. As a consequence, after executing the test for a certain amount of time the actual proportion of requests (of each type) will be the different than the targeted request proportion.